# Extract a constant from a constant (accessibility of variables)

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

With React Native and React Navigation, I can change my title with `navigationOptions` :

```
const ForumScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const forum = navigation.getParam('forum')

  ...
}

IndexScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    title: 'My Forum',
  }
}

export default ForumScreen
```

But I want to use my `forum` variable of `ForumScreen` component.

I tried this but I got an error because the variable is not accessible :

```
...
IndexScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    title: forum.name,
  }
}
...
```

Comment: What is the return value of `FourmScreen` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your example `forum` variable is defined in scope of the ForumScreen function and inavailable outside.

You can try to lift variable up storing it in a parent component of both ForumScreen and IndexScreen (for example in Redux Store or top-level React Component)

```
class Parent {
  state = {
    forum: null
  }

  setForum(forum) {
    this.setState({ forum })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ForumScreen setForum={this.setForum} />
        <IndexForum forum={this.state.forum} />
      </>
   )
  }
}
```

```js
const ForumScreen = ({ setForum, navigation }) => {
  const forum = navigation.getParam('forum')
  setForum(forum):
  ...
}
```

I understood now, that navigationOptions is a static method. It's not connected with IndexScreen `this`. You have to pass forum as a param like below

```js
IndexScreen.navigationOptions = (forum) => {
 return {
   title: forum.name,
 }
}
```

or make navigationOptions non-static.

One more way, but its not React way

```js
let forum;
const ForumScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  forum = navigation.getParam('forum');
}
```